# "I'll be around" - idiom?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

In films and in games I often here the construction **"I'll be around"**

There are also song titles **"I'll be around"**.

The 'popular dictionaries' have very many meaning for the word *"around"* but no matter whether it is a preposition or an adverb it doesn't have a meaning of *"in the vicinity"* if it's what I suppose this construction means. Could it be an idiom?

What other choices do we have?

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/around), 7; [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around), 2c; [Longman's](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/around), 4b; [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/around), 5.

Comment: @StoneyB Strange, seems my eyes have slipped pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more to do with reading between the lines than actually referring to staying *close* to something/someone. For instance,

> "I'll be around.. when the time comes..." OR
>
> "I'll be around.. when you need me..".

So, it is more like saying that I'll be *available*. IMO, it has nothing to do with *vicinity* in this context.

**EDIT:**

Turns out that [be-around](http://www.yourdictionary.com/be-around) has an **idiom**atic meaning which says "to be alive, existent, or present".

Comment: This is exactly what I want to know. Why *"around"*?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what dictionaries you're looking at, but [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/around) and even a Google search for "define around" show up with meanings of "near, in the vicinity of" and/or "in existence".

In the case of a sentence like this...

> I'll be around to help you when you need it.

"around" means nearby, either physically or metaphorically. It has a sense of ambiguity, meaning that the speaker's exact location is not given and might change over time, but they will still be near somehow.

Extending this meaning, "around" can be used to mean "still here" or "in existence" in sentences like this:

> That business will still be around in 20 years.
>
> Other people have come and gone, but I'm still around.